# CoreData model update crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

When I update my CoreData model, it crashes the app, So I have to delete the old app, and then reinstall. That's fine with me, but my question is: How do I tell my customer that they must delete the app before they reinstall? This seems too complicated...I am just adding 1 additonal field to a models and that's it.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: Just clear the database, delete all entries.

Comment: Ramy: migration is a better idea. More work for the programmer, but better experience for the customer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up database migration... To upgrade a customer's existing data to the newest data model when they update. For some changes Core Data can do it for you. For others you'll have to write the migration code yourself.

Perhaps start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: It's a pain, but will offer a superior user experience, which is what separates good apps from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Nielsbot said, there's a migration system that Core Data uses.

You can create new versions of your model and select which one to use. There's a little bit of code to change in your AppDelegate method where the persistent store coordinator loads the model to tell it to load versions. I'd suggest you read Apple's documentation on how to implement this at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding one field to a table then you can create a new version of the database. Keep the current one unchanged.

In one of the menus there is a create new data version or something.

Make the changes in the new version.

There are numerous tutorials about how to do this.

If you release an update that crashes the app then apple won't approve it so you will have to so this anyway.